# how to take value from input with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need some enlightenment. 
Right now, I'm learning vue.js, and I want to know how to take all data value from input form?? I want take all data from there & save into my database. But, I still don't know, how to get all these data.. thx

```
<div id="example-1">
        <form>
            <input v-model="info.name">
            <input v-model="info.nickname">
            <input v-model="info.gender">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" v-on:click="submitData">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var example1 = new Vue({
                el: '#example-1',
                data: {
                    info: {
                        name: '',
                        nickname: '',
                        gender: ''
                    }
                }
            },
            methods: {
                submitData: function() {
                    console.log(this.info);
                    // this.$http.post('/api/something', JSON.stringify(this.info));
                }
            })
    </script>
```

Comment: The commented out line in the submitData function will post the data to a URL. You need to have a back end service at that URL the can read the posted data and put it into your database.

Comment: i already have back end to handle this, but i just want to know, how to get all these data from input from. Thx

Comment: The back end should receive the stringified `this.info` that should contain all the form data.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you need to *prevent the default action*.  When you submit a form, the page automatically reloads.  You won't ever see a response from the server in the **console** because it will clear when the page refreshes after the submission action.

Go [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), and ctrl + f 'Event Modifiers'.  You'll want to use `.prevent` in this case, then write your own code to handle the submission / response.